# Is there a way to pass vue model values into method function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I recently started using Vue Js and I am stuck at this point where I cant pass vue model values to method function.

```
<div v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.customerName">
   <input type="text" v-model="post.customerName" /> /** successfully print customerName inside this field**/

   <b-button block pill variant="outline-info" v-on:click="bookerName()">
       {{post.customerName}}
   </b-button>
</div>
```

Method Function

```
bookerName(){
console.log(this.post.customerName); /** prints out UNDEFINED **/
}
```

VUE data return

```
posts:{
  customerName:{ 'David','John','Sam'},
},

bookerName: ''
```

Comment: You would want to pass in the `post` to the method as an argument, or the `index` as an argument, and use the index against the `posts` array to get the related post element

Comment: Your data would yield a syntax error. Is posts an object or an array?

Comment: this.post doesn't exist on your vue component. You can see that the data object does not contain a posts key. Instead you'll need to pass the post to the method when binding it. `v-on:click="bookerName(post)"` so you can access the scoped variable `bookerName(post) { /* post is now available */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the index from `v-for` to the method, and get the value by index:

```html
<b-button v-on:click="bookerName(index)">
...
```

```js
bookerName (index){
  console.log(this.posts[index])
}
```

Also, in your example you have `bookerName: ''`. Is it a property inside `data()`? If so, you cannot have method with the same name `bookerName`